# Database/cloud solution for very wide time series data (i.e. spectra with up to 8196 columns)?

Tags: database-recommendation, time-series-database

I'm dealing with data from a science project which comes from a multi-channel analyzer: once per minute I get 2048 integer values from one device and 8192 integer values from another device. Both devices operate continuously 24/7.

I want to store each of these vectors with a timestamp in a dedicated table which I can later query to select subsets of time ranges and/or columns (which represent energy ranges).

So far I'm using CSV files to store the data. I have one file per device per day and add a row each time I get a new vector. When I analyze such data, I read the relevant CSV files in as data frames in R or Python and merge them into one large data frame. Now I'm looking for a better/faster solution.

Any recommendations on what kind of database or service I could use for this kind of very wide (but not very long) time series data?

Comment: In Postgres you could create a table with an integer array that stores those values (together with the device ID and the timestamp). But I don't know if you can deal with that in R

Comment: Thank you. I looked at different Postgres variants and ended up working with TimescaleDB. So far I am very happy with it. It offers the kind of functionality I was looking for. As for performance, I will need to see once I have more data.